# Calling jquery function error: "Uncaught ReferenceError: ui is not defined"

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

This is my jquery function which I call:

```
var spinSeconds = function(event, ui, id) {
            if (ui.value >= 60) {
                $(this).spinner('value', ui.value - 60);
                $("#" + id).spinner('stepUp');
                return false;
            } else if (ui.value < 0) {
                $(this).spinner('value', ui.value + 60);
                $("#" +  id).spinner('stepDown');
                return false;
            }
        }
```

This is where I call it:

```
$('#seconds').spinner({
    spin: spinSeconds(event, ui, "minutes")
});
```

When I try to pass id as an argument and call it like above, my function does not work and gives

> "Uncaught ReferenceError: ui is not defined"

on console. What is the correct way to call it?

**UPDATE:**

You can see jsfidle here: https://jsfiddle.net/86Lwhmem/

Answer (score 0):

Try this : defined your jquery function like below but before calling it. call it in same manner as you have posted. It should work.

```
var  spinSeconds = function(event, ui, id) {
            if (ui.value >= 60) {
                $(this).spinner('value', ui.value - 60);
                $("#" + id).spinner('stepUp');
                return false;
            } else if (ui.value < 0) {
                $(this).spinner('value', ui.value + 60);
                $("#" +  id).spinner('stepDown');
                return false;
            }
        };
```

Comment: It gives this error where I call the function: "Uncaught ReferenceError: ui is not defined"

Comment: check ui variable in `spin: spinSeconds(event, ui, "minutes")` call. It should be global or defined inside function

Comment: Not defined inside my function, it is global.

Comment: can you reproduce this on jsfiddle and share the link?